# How to execute the vim commands through shell script

Tags: linux, shell, sh, vim

Hi I have a situation as

I have a writing a shell script where I have to pass input to the **vim**.

Explaining in detail

Here I have already written shell script that I cannot changed. Here is the code for it.

```
 sudo vim /mnt/etc/{hosts,hostname,ports}
```

due to this hosts file is opened we can go manually next to the hostname file by **:n** and similar for the ports file.

But I have to perform same operation from my **.sh** file. 
Also I have to edit the ports file and after completing it I have to save and quite it through **:wq** command.

How can I do it?

Comment: Do you mean open the file interactively, or make edits directly in the  script file?  If the latter, can you give us more details on the edits you need to make?  If the former, why can't you just put that command as-is in your `.sh file` and run it?

Comment: @Donovan From the title I thought it was the latter — “execute… commands through shell script”.

Comment: it's not clear, and vi is not intended to be used that way.  It's a visual editor.  If you need to modify file contents programmatically, `sed` (the stream editor) would be the way to do it.

Comment: @Donovan it means it is not possible to do it through vim? or i have to changed the above command.

Comment: If you are writing a shell script it is because you want to automatize a task, but editing with vim is not something that can/should be automatized. If the core of the task is text processing, add or edit, you can use other tools like `sed`, `awk`, `cat >>`.

Comment: @riscube4 it means you should be using `sed` or `awk` if you want to modify files via a shell script, not `vi`.

Comment: @riscube4 Also, that the end goal is not clearly defined yet. If you explain with more detail what you want to do, maybe someone will have more precise advise.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Alternatives

Unless you really need special Vim capabilities, you're probably better off using *non-interactive tools* like `sed`, `awk`, or Perl / Python / Ruby / *your favorite scripting language here*.

That said, you can use Vim non-interactively:

### Silent Batch Mode

For very simple text processing (i.e. using Vim like an enhanced 'sed' or 'awk', maybe just benefitting from the enhanced regular expressions in a `:substitute` command), use *Ex-mode*.

```
# Unix
vim -T dumb --noplugin -n -es -S "commands.ex" "filespec"
```

Attention: Vim will hang waiting for input if the `"commands.ex"` file doesn't exist; better check beforehand for its existence! Alternatively, Vim can read the commands from stdin. You can also fill a new buffer with text read from stdin, and read commands from stderr if you use the `-` argument.

### Full Automation

For more advanced processing involving multiple windows, and real automation of Vim (where you might interact with the user or leave Vim running to let the user take over), use:

```
vim -N -u NONE -n -c "set nomore" -S "commands.vim" "filespec"
```

Here's a summary of the used arguments:

```
-T dumb           Avoids errors in case the terminal detection goes wrong.
-N -u NONE        Do not load vimrc and plugins, alternatively:
--noplugin        Do not load plugins.
-n                No swapfile.
-es               Ex mode + silent batch mode -s-ex
                Attention: Must be given in that order!
-S ...            Source script.
-c 'set nomore'   Suppress the more-prompt when the screen is filled
                with messages or output to avoid blocking.
```

Comment: Thanks for reply I have used `sed` and made some changes finally it worked.