# need to write a script to change file format from dos to unix

Tags: vim

I have to make a script using vim which opens a file, set the fileformat=unix, and then save the file and exit. Could you please help? Thanks

Comment: Do you really need vim?

Comment: vim would be better -sed could be an alternative, but I tried and i was not able to make it working

Comment: You don't need an editor at all: just use `dos2unix` if you have it or can have it.

Comment: The reason I posted this question is that after updating OS dos2unix is not longer available (in centos6.4)

Comment: OK. It's listed [here](http://mirror.centos.org/centos/6/os/x86_64/Packages/) though.

Comment: Centos has a dos2unix package, but it is very old (version 3.1). You can better build dos2unix yourself from source. The latest version is 6.0.4. It's not difficult.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, check out whether you have a `dos2unix` or `dos2ux` command; it already does this for you.

With Vim, this should do the job:

```
$ vim -c "wq ++ff=unix" filename
```

This one in-lines the `fileformat` change with the `:w` command; of course, you can also do this separately via `-c "set ff=unix"`.

#### Notes

- You can also do this via a variety of tools, e.g. `sed`, `perl`, ...; Vim is a quite heavyweight alternative.
- This still starts up a full, interactive Vim instance. Have a look [at this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20616006/813602) which additional command-line arguments can turn Vim into batch mode.

Comment: `sed -i 's/\r$//' dosfile`